# C++ Label allow English and Cyrillic Text

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am brand new to C++. I want to allow text from a file that may have normal English and Cyrillic text how can I display it on a label without any errors?

Comment: When you mention Label - you are probably thinking of a GUI of some sort.  If you are brand new, stick to console output and learn the basics first instead of launching straight into GUIs.

Comment: Hi, yeah I was looking into GTK to do display but also even for console, unsure how to output the different types of text.

Comment: Did you ever hear about Unicode and UTF-8? FYI: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) AFAIR: GTK has a superior support for UTF-8. (It already had when I was programming with GTK+ / gtkmm 2 - on Windows.)

Comment: What language are you coming from?